# Syntax for Media Url subfolder

Tags: magento-1.9

The line below works to display an attribute image instead of the attribute text on the product page (CE 1.9.2). Can someone please tell me the correct syntax to replace /myfolder/media/attributes/ with a reference to the MediaURL or if there is a better way to do this?

```
   <?php $ce=$_product->getAttributeText('ce');
echo '<a href="/'.str_replace(' ', '_',$ce).'"><img src="/myfolder/media/attributes/'.str_replace(' ', '_',$ce).'.png" alt="'.$ce.'"></a>' ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is myfolder your magento installation folder? I am assuming so.

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getUrl('media/attributes')?>xxxxx.jpg?>"/>
```

In your code :

```
<?php echo '<a href="/'.str_replace(' ', '_',$ce).'"><img src="'.$this->getUrl('media/attributes').str_replace(' ', '_',$ce).'.png" alt="'.$ce.'"></a>' ?>
```